# Android/Java(?) - accessing parent from child

Tags: java, android

I am (trying to) making a simple boardgame. Its UI should be very simple, a top component representing a drawing of the board itself, and on the bottom, a few `TextView`s giving some relevant info (turns, number of tokens on the board, current player, ...).

I have an `Activity`, with:

- A `Game` member, which handles all the logic.
- A `BoardView` extending `View`, to draw the game board, which handles the interaction.
- `TextView`s which should show some additional interaction.

So the `BoardView` and `TextView` instances need to access info from their sibling `Game`. How shall I access it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either construct both classes `BoardView` and `TextView` with the same `Game` instance,

```
Game game = new Game();
BoardView board = new BoardView(game);
TextView text = new TextView(game);
```

or make `Game` a singleton which holds its own instance.

```
public class Game{

private Game game;
//private constructor
private Game(){};    

//synchronised method to create a game instance
private  synchronized static void createInstance () {
    if (game == null) game = new Game ();
}


public static void getInstance(){
  if(game==null){
    createInstance();
  }
  return game;
}
```

Then you can get the same game instance in both classes by calling

```
Game game = Game.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin's answer from above is what you need.
You can try MVC pattern with an implementation as suggested [here](http://www.cs.otago.ac.nz/cosc346/labs/COSC346-lab2.2up.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a lot. As you have probably guessed I am not a programmer by trade, but by hobby. I suppose these "singleton" and "MVC" patterns are important notions I should get acquainted with.